# How can i load ICanHaz.js templates with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, icanhaz.js

I read on ICanHaz.js documentation that i should load templates from a remote like this

```
$.getJSON('/myserver/templates.json', function (templates) {
    $.each(templates, function (template) {
        ich.addTemplate(template.name, template.template);
    });
});
```

I have no idea how the json template should look like, would really appreciate an example ICanHaz.js json template.

Thanks

Comment: I belive it's an array of objects with structure: `{name:'bla/bla/bla', template: 'template string <%= whatever %>'}`, that maybe you dynamically create by reading a directory tree of templates.

Comment: oh yes ofcourse, im so dumb! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save some time on debugging $.each requires two arguments to the callback function: iterator and actual object

```
$.getJSON('/myserver/templates.json', function (templates) {        
    $.each(templates, function (id, template) {
        ich.addTemplate(template.name, template.template);
    });        
});
```

Of course you must remember to set promise since these templates are loaded in async mode.